# Moq Unit testing with multiple callbacks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

(First off, please excuse the pseudocode. Didn't have a choice there.)

I'm new to unit testing and am having some trouble. I'm attempting to unit test a controller method that makes two calls to a service, eg.

```
public JsonResult Submit(FormModel form){
    RequestObj obj = createRequestObj(form);
    bool response = _someService.SubmitRequest(obj);

    if(form.RerunWithAnotherValue) {
        obj.SomeProp = "New Value";
        obj.SomeOtherProp = false;
        _someService.SubmitRequest(obj);
    }

    return new JsonResult {
        Data = new { status = "OK" }
    };
}
```

It's simple enough to test it without the conditional value that resubmits:

```
protected bool _response;
protected RequestObj _request;
...
_someServiceMock.Setup(x => x.SubmitRequest(It.IsAny<RequestObj>()))
          .Returns(_response)
          .Callback((RequestObj request) =>
          {  
              _request = request;
          })
          .Verifiable();
```

I can then test using _request. But with the conditional, the values of _request are always equal to those of the second service call. So if I want to assert that SomeOtherProp is true, it will always fail due to the second.

`Assert.IsTrue(_request.SomeOtherProp)` is always false, even if it is true on the first call. The same is true with `Assert.IsTrue(_response)`, but I suspect I can fix that with multiple Returns.

Is there a way to assign only the first call via Callback and ignore the other? Better yet, can I save them to different objects and test them separately? I looked at `SetupSequence` but `.Callback` didn't work there. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Example test:

```
[Test]
public void request_object_has_property() {
    Assert.IsTrue(_request.SomeOtherProp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [`Verify`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) not suit your needs here for some reason?  You can verify both calls like this:

```
// first call
_someServiceMock.Verify(x => x.SubmitRequest(It.Is<RequestObj>(
    o => o.SomeOtherProp), Times.Once());

// second call
_someServiceMock.Verify(x => x.SubmitRequest(It.Is<RequestObj>(
    o => o.SomeProp == "New Value" && !o.SomeOtherProp), Times.Once());
```

This verifies that `SubmitRequest` was called once with a parameter that matches the given predicate in the `It.Is` expressions.

Comment: I'm using [Verify](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) only to check that it was successful at least once:  `_someServiceMock.Verify(x=>x.SubmitRequest(It.IsAny<RequestObj>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);`   Added additional information to the original question. That link you posted is a good read, so thanks for that. I will poke around in there.

Comment: The two tests I have shown would replace that check and be more strict.

Comment: Good point, but I should have given some context. The method was extended to include that conditional second call. This broke the existing unit tests. I am attempting to fix the existing tests that make assertions on the values of `_request`. I may be able to scrap many of these old tests and use `Verify` in the end. For now I'm just trying to fix existing.